# next.js app and rest api on the same server

Tags: node.js, nginx, next.js, pm2

I have a next.js app deployed with pm2 on remote server that uses nginx as a reverse proxy and want to connect it to my express rest api that is deployed on the same server with pm2, the express api is only meant to comunicate with my next app, in local development works without problems, but in the server the next app is serving to the internet well but has no conection with the api even when it's running.

here are my pm2 config files:

api

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'c2 back',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      cron_restart: '0 */24 * * *',
      instances: '2', // Or a number of instances
      script: './src/index.js',
      args: 'start',
      env_development: {
        PORT: 3005,
        NODE_ENV: 'development',
      },
      env_production: {
        PORT: 8080,
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

next app

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'c2 front',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      cron_restart: '0 */24 * * *',
      instances: '2', // Or a number of instances
      script: 'node_modules/next/dist/bin/next',
      args: 'start',
      env_local: {
        APP_ENV: 'local' // APP_ENV=local
      },
      env_development: {
        APP_ENV: 'dev' // APP_ENV=dev
      },
      env_production: {
        APP_ENV: 'prod' // APP_ENV=prod
      }
    }
  ]
}
```